Determine what numbers must be filled into the shaded squares to make the grid (now with ten squares filled in) puzzle-ready
A 5x5 Latin Square is a 5x5 grid of squares in which each square contains one of the numbers 1 through 5 such that every number appears exactly once in each row and column. A partially completed grid (with numbers in some of the squares) is puzzle-ready if there is a unique way to fill in the remaining squares to complete a Latin Square.
Below is a partially completed grid with seven squares filled in and an additional three squares shaded. Determine what numbers must be filled into the shaded squares to make the grid (now with ten squares filled in) puzzle-ready, and then complete the Latin Square.


Attribution:  USA Mathematical Talent Search 2021-2022.
The deadline for submitting answers to this talent search was November 29, 2021.

First, consider the centre box:

 It must be a 1 or a 4. If it's a 1, then the two squares in the bottom right must also be 1s:


 And after a few more deductions, we're left with a board with two distinct solutions:

 So it's a 4. Next, the middle-left box can either be a 3 or a 4. If it's a 4, the square above it must be a 5 and the one below a 3:

 And continuing from here also results in multiple distinct solutions:
 
 So it's a 3. Then, the remaining black square must be either a 1, 2 or 4. If it's 1, then the bottom centre box must have the remaining 1:

 And a few more deductions lead to a board that also has two distinct solutions:

 If it's a 2, then we can start deducing the squares in its row and column:

 And a few more deductions lead to yet another board with multiple distinct solutions, although it's the closest so far:

 Now, if we put a 4 in:

 We can start making deductions:

 And this finally leads to a unique solution!


